# Will I lose my green card after divorce?

Tags: usa, greencard, marriage, california, divorce

I am a new F-1 student in the US. My classmate likes to get marry with me. I want to know if I marry with a US citizen or Green Card holder, will I get either a permanent or temporary/conditional Green Card?

Also if we get divorce after a while(either 1 day after marriage or more) will I lose my Green Card?

Comment: If you think your proposed marriage might end up in divorce after just one day, you should probably read up on articles like this https://www.stilt.com/blog/2020/08/what-is-the-penalty-for-marrying-for-a-green-card/ and this http://myattorneyusa.com/marriage-fraud

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you immigrate by being petitioned by a US citizen or permanent resident, and you have been married for less than 2 years on the date you become a permanent resident, you will become a conditional permanent resident with a 2-year green card, and you will have to apply for Removal of Conditions. If you have been married for more than 2 years on the date you become a permanent resident, you will become a non-conditional permanent resident with a 10-year green card.

If you divorce before you become a permanent resident, you cannot become a permanent resident on the basis of your ex-spouse's petition anymore.

If your marriage was (and you can show that it was) bona fide (i.e. it was not entered into to circumvent the immigration laws), but later falls apart and you divorce at any time after you become a permanent resident, you can keep your green card. This is true no matter if you are a conditional or non-conditional permanent resident at the time you divorce. If you are a conditional permanent resident, you can apply for Removal of Conditions by yourself on the basis that the marriage ended in divorce. (Of course, in that case, you can expect extra scrutiny regarding whether your marriage was bona fide).

If your marriage is fraudulent (i.e. entered into in order to circumvent the immigration laws), any status you obtained through it can be revoked when this is found out. This is true no matter if you become a conditional or non-conditional permanent resident, and no matter how long after you get your green card before you divorce (or even if you do not divorce). And even if you go through the naturalization process to supposedly become a US citizen, that naturalization can still be revoked if it is found that there was fraud in any part of your immigration process.

Comment: The question says "may classmate likes to get married with me," not "many classmate..."  It's quite possible that the intention was to say "my classmate..."; at least, that's how I read it at first.

Comment: @phoog: Hmm that does make more sense; I'll delete that paragraph

Comment: @phoog: You right, Thanks for correction.

Comment: @user102008: Thank you very much for your complete answer. Just one more question: "What if the marriage was not fraudulent and was a real marriage, but the citizen/GC holder spouse claims it was a fake marriage just for revenge?"

Comment: @GoodMan: They can claim whatever they want, but that doesn't mean the government will believe them. After you get your green card, your status is between you and the government. The government is aware that sometimes ex-spouses say things out of spite, and will take that into consideration when evaluating the evidence of potential fraud. The government will need to be convinced that there was fraud before initiating deportation proceedings against you in immigration court, where you will be able to challenge it with your evidence showing that there was no fraud.

Comment: Should you prove the marriage was a real marriage while you getting divorce? How can you prove that?

Comment: @GoodMan: You would provide as much evidence as you can, including intermingled finances (shared accounts, shared insurance, beneficiaries on each other's accounts, etc.), any children you had together, any photos and text messages of you being together, etc.

Comment: Thank you. As my last question, should anyone (No US citizen or PRs) who gets married and divorced with a US citizen/PR, provide a prove of the marriage wasn't fraudulent? Or it depends on the court and if they get suspicious about the case?

Comment: @GoodMan: First, it's not marriage and divorce that's the issue, but marriage that's only made for an immigration benefit. And there doesn't necessarily need to be divorce -- two people conspiring to have a fraudulent marriage might remain married. If you are applying for a green card or doing Removal of Conditions, then you will need to prove that the marriage was genuine. But otherwise as a non-conditional permanent resident, you don't need to spontaneously prove to anyone that the marriage is genuine. If they suspect your marriage is fraudulent they can put you in removal proceedings.